# Content System managment in SharePoint2010

Tags: sql-server-2008, sharepoint-2010

How is it going ?
I am new to SharePoint 2010. My manager told me that we need to install SP 2010 server to manage some content for the managers that we've got. 
I installed SP2010 (standalone). Now the thing is that my boss need is to allow the management of the company (General Manager, HR, Payroll, IT Manager) to send a content to special manager they can select, and they will receive a notification to open that content. 
What I am asking is:

- a little specific details about what is this called in SharePoint 2010 to google it and try to find out about it.
  Notice that these managers will log in using Active directory.
  And these contents are going to be saved into Microsoft SQL server 2008 
  Thank you guys, and sorry for the long story ;)

Answer (score 1):

I believe that you are looking for this --> http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook-help/CH001050210.aspx

they are called "Alerts" in the world of SharePoint

a user can "subscribe" to follow a specific item, or the contents of a complete list

Comment: Thank you so much, but I think I am looking for SharePoint 2010 server

Comment: Because these content going to be registered into an sql server 2008